# Executing a binary with a shared library in linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, shared-libraries

I am making a simple hello world program to learn about linking shared libraries in linux. I have managed to compile the main program into an executable with the shared library using the following:

```
g++ -fPIC -c lab2_hello_main.cpp    <--create position independent objects

g++ -fPIC -c lab2_hello_sub.cpp

g++ -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname=libfuncs.so.1.0 *.o -o libfuncs.so.1.0 -lc <--make the shared library

ln -s libfuncs.so.1.0 libfuncs.so <-- soft links for compiling and running

ln -s libfuncs.so.1.0 libfuncs.so.1

g++ -o hello_dyn lab2_hello_main.cpp -L/mypath -lfuncs <-- Linking the library to main
```

When I do an ldd on hello_dyn I get an output stating that the library can't be found:

`"libfuncs.so.1.0 => not found"`
The other libraries it looks for automatically are fine.

Anyone know why this might be?

Comment: google LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Just what I needed to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shared library's location is not in the linker's search path.  You can confirm this by adding the directory in which your library is located to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable and then run `ldd` again.  See the [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) man page for details.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the prompt response!